# Why does OpenModelica allow to connect an input-type connection port to another input-type connection port?

Tags: openmodelica

If I understood it correctly, only connections between an input and an output port/variable should be allowed...

Is there a way to restrict possible connections to input-to-output connections only (so that input-input (or output-output) connections will not be allowed anymore)?

Comment: We haven't implemented that check yet. Is on the list of things to be done but there are other priorities first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.